# There is ORDER for HTML tag attributes

Tags: html, input, attributes, tags

I tried the same attributes for input tag but different order, the layout will be difference. I think tag's attributes are no order, can you explain to me?
By the way, class field as below:

```
.field {
  font-family: "MS UI Gothic";
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #ADD566;
  readonly: false;
}
```

Input1 tag:

[image: input1.jpg]

Input2 tag:

[image]

```css
   .field {
   font-family: "MS UI Gothic";
   font-size: 12px;
   height: 17px;
   border: 1px solid #ADD566;
   readonly: false;
    }
```

```html
Input1 tag:

 <input name="code" size="9" maxlength="6" type="text" onChange="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" style="ime-mode:disabled; text-transform:uppercase"　class="field" value="">

Input2 tag:

 <input name="code" size="9" maxlength="6" type="text" class="field" onChange="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" style="ime-mode:disabled; text-transform:uppercase"　value="">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special character (`U+3000 : IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE`) before class, use white space (`U+0020 : SPACE [SP]`) only.

> You can test it here: http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html

### Your code:

```css
.field {
  font-family: "MS UI Gothic";
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #ADD566 !important;
  readonly: false;
}
```

```html
 Input1 tag:
<input name="code" size="9" maxlength="6" type="text" onChange="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" style="ime-mode:disabled; text-transform:uppercase"　class="field" value="">
Input2 tag:
<input name="code" size="9" maxlength="6" type="text" class="field" onChange="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" style="ime-mode:disabled; text-transform:uppercase" value="">
```

### After replacing it with white space:

```css
.field {
  font-family: "MS UI Gothic";
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #ADD566 !important;
  readonly: false;
}
```

```html
Input1 tag:
<input name="code" size="9" maxlength="6" type="text" onChange="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" style="ime-mode:disabled; text-transform:uppercase" class="field" value="">
Input2 tag:
<input name="code" size="9" maxlength="6" type="text" class="field" onChange="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" style="ime-mode:disabled; text-transform:uppercase" value="">
```

Comment: @mikezang glad to help ;D